# New-CimSession not connecting to the remote machine

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop, remote, remote-control

I have created the powershell script to display the taskschedulars in the remote machine.

```
$User = "<domain-name>\<user-name>"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<domain-password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

$cimsession = New-CimSession -ComputerName <member-machine-name> -Credential $Credential -Authentication Negotiate

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\UpdateTasks\*" -CimSession $cimsession
```

I get the output as

```
New-CimSession : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the 
service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the 
WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM 
service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm 
quickconfig".
At line:5 char:15
+ ... imsession = New-CimSession -ComputerName <member-machine-name> -Credential $Cre ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (:) [New-CimSession], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338012,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimSession 
   Command
    + PSComputerName        : <member-machine-name>
```

I have checked and changed the winrm in member machine using  winrm quickconfig and finally getting the result

```
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

Can anyone help me with this and what i am doing wrong in this? Any settings need to be configured?

Comment: My shot in the dark would be that either a) the host that wants to connect doesn't know the destination hose (different subnets?) or b) a Firewall inbetween the host blocks the request (either a physical or software firewall)

Comment: while it seems unlikely, you MAY need to add the target systems to your `TrustedHosts` list. this >>> How to add servers to TrustedHosts list via PowerShell and command Prompt for the WinRM client | Learn [Solve IT] — https://techdirectarchive.com/2020/03/23/how-to-add-trusted-host-for-the-winrm-client/